# Using siunitx to format hex digits

Tags: formatting, siunitx

Is it possible to tell the `\siunitx` package to treat some letters as digits? For instance, it would be nice to be able to format hexadecimal numbers using

```
$\num[digit-group-size=4]{6789ABCDEF}_{16}$
```

But this currently fails with

> Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '6789ABCDEF

The desired output with the code below would be something like:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}

\begin{document}

$\num{123456789}$

$\num[digit-group-size=4]{123456789}_{16}$

$\num[digit-group-size=4]{6789ABCDE}_{16}$% <-- How can I do something like this
%%%$6\,789\texttt{A}\,\texttt{BCDE}_{16}$% <---- Manual solution

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `input-digits`, likely along with `mode = text` and `input-exponent-markers`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-digits = 1234567890ABCDEF,
  input-exponent-markers = , mode = text}
\begin{document}

\num{123ABCDE}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You code as given works as desired. However, if add a `D` as in `\num{123ABCD}`. or an `E` as in `\num{123ABCE}`,  I get `Invalid number`  However, `\num{123ABCF}` seems to work.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'd forgotten to set `input-exponent-markers` to an empty value